# why integer data gets inserted into 'varchar' column without giving the single quotes?

Tags: mysql, implicit-conversion

```
create table student(id int, name varchar(20));
```

student table created here.*

```
insert into student values(20,100);
```

In above query I am inserting the integer value 100 in **name** column, which is **varchar**. Why its not giving an error or how its getting inserted?

edit 1: But while inserting a string it is necessary to give single quotes?
           Ex. **insert into student values(20,suraj);**  *gives error*

Comment: Because it is easy to convert integers to strings.  The database does implicit conversion.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: MySQL doesn't care and does the *close  enough* thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is handled differently with different databases. For MySQL, an integer is implicitly converted to a varchar for you, but in SQL, it produces an error. As for MySQL, the auto conversion is just part of the loose types some languages have for convenience.

If you want to force MySQL to do type checking, you can use STRICT_ALL_TABLES in your config file. You can also set it in your current session via:

```
$ SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables

Hope this helps!

edit 1: With string literals, languages typically require quotes so that the program knows it is a string and not a keyword. For example, if your string was "select", MySQL would need to know you meant that as a string.

Comment: Now I understood the implicit conversion. But, why would they provide such implicit conversion? I mean, this could harm data integrity.

Comment: What example would you have where integrity is harmed? if you take 10 or '10' the both end up as '10' in the database.  if you take 'one' and try to store it in a numeric column an error will be produced.  If you take '2017-01-01' and compare it to a date, the compare works; so long as the date format is supported.

Comment: I think it's just a convenience thing as per the database design for MySQL. PHP, javascript and bash are also loose with their types.

Comment: @xQbert You are right. But, why while inserting a string its necessary to give quotes?

Comment: Probably because that's the way strings were defined in the ANSI SQL standards; but i'm looking for that now.  Not able to find it easily yet...  think about it if your string was 'She asked, "How are you?"' without the single quotes to offset the comma and the quotes, the database may think you're trying to insert 'She asked' in one column and , "how are you?" in another... so the ' just denote structure. but I can't site a source yet.  Put another way, because that's the way the compiler knows how to interpret character data.

Comment: Numbers are easy to tokenize in the SQL string, they're always contiguous, never contain spaces. Arbitrary user strings are not. Some kind of beginning and end of string identifier is required, and by convention that's either `'` or `"`.

Comment: in most SQL engines, the " denotes beginning and end of a field or table name; especially those using a space or other special characters.  They can in some engines be used to denote string data as well; but I suggest sticking to `'` for character data and `"` for table/field names. (If needed) though mySQL uses backticks... sigh